# Syntax error near "AS"

Tags: sql, postgresql, ddl

I am trying to execute the below statement, and I'm getting an error stating

> ERROR:  syntax error at or near "AS"

Below is my SQL statement

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS temp_users 
AS 
(SELECT patient.patientid as patient 
 FROM patients 
 WHERE patient.name = "Ann");
```

My Postgres version is 9.5.6. I tried many ways but failed. Does anyone know the fix for this?

Comment: The parentheses aren't needed, and are probably what's causing your syntax problem.

Comment: Is there any content **before** the statement?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are selecting from a table named `patients` so the reference to `patient` in `patient.patientid` is invalid, the same for `patient.name` (although I don't know why the error references the `as`, it should rather be "*missing FROM-clause entry for table "patient"*")

Also: string constants need to be put in single quotes, not double quotes. And the parentheses around the select are useless.

The following should work:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS temp_users 
AS 
SELECT p.patientid as patient 
FROM patients p
WHERE p.name = 'Ann';
```

Online example: http://rextester.com/PVMT64289

Answer (score 0):

In my postgres it is working. No error found.

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS temp_users 
AS (SELECT test.id as patient FROM test  WHERE test.name = 'Ann');
```